# How to filter for a prerequiste

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, filter

```
SELECT 
    Staff.FullName, Skills.Name, Staff.Team, StaffSkills.Rating
FROM
    StaffSkills
INNER JOIN 
    Staff ON  Staff.Id = StaffSkills.StaffId
INNER JOIN 
    Skills ON Skills.Id = StaffSkills.SkillId
WHERE 
    Staff.Team LIKE '%financial services%' 
    AND (Skills.Name LIKE '%SDLC%' OR Skills.Name LIKE '%prince2%' OR  
         Skills.Name LIKE '%agile%' OR Skills.Name LIKE '%waterfall%' OR 
         Skills.Name LIKE '%oracle%' OR Skills.Name LIKE '%stakeholder%' OR 
         Skills.Name LIKE '%leadership%' OR Skills.Name LIKE '%negotiation%' OR  
         Skills.Name LIKE '%planning%')
```

My goal is to filter the results so that it shows all people under financial services who hold the skill of "%project management%" - I would also like the results to show further skills (if they hold any) - so anything after the OR clause, if they hold a skill named there, it should show on my results.

Inserting expected results shortly, bear with me.

Comment: The rules are unclear.  only return users on the financial services team with a skill of project management. AND those users with any of your listed other skills regardless of team and having project management skill?  Show a example result it would help clarify your need.  and why so many "LIke" statements... can't it be an equality check?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear.  Maybe it would help if you show us some sample data along with what output you want.

Comment: Please show expected output. It will also be useful to have a mock create table and insert data script to save time for those trying to help you

Comment: That said your query probably needs a self (outer) join with the skills table to get the additional skills if I understand your requirement correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to see only staff members who are financial services project managers, but you also want to see their other skills.  Right now you are filtering to only see records with the specific team/skill of financial services and project management.  If you instead pull `ID`s for these people, using a subquery, you can return all of their skills.  Something like this:

```
SELECT Staff.FullName, Skills.Name, Staff.Team, StaffSkills.Rating
FROM   StaffSkills
INNER JOIN Staff ON Staff.Id = StaffSkills.StaffId
INNER JOIN Skills ON Skills.Id  =StaffSkills.SkillId
WHERE Staff.ID in (
        SELECT Staff.ID
        FROM StaffSkills
        INNER JOIN Staff ON Staff.Id = StaffSkills.StaffId
        INNER JOIN Skills ON Skills.Id  =StaffSkills.SkillId
        WHERE Staff.Team LIKE '%financial services%' 
        AND Skills.Name LIKE '%project management%')
```

Edit:  Also you should consider changing `LIKE` to `=` where possible.  Or if nothing else, use only one wildcard `%`.  `=` and `LIKE 'abc%'` can make use of indexes.  Double wildcards `'%abc%'` will not (full string seeks).

Comment: Thank you - will give this a try in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

play with this and see if it helps ... I came up with that just editing on notepad .... need more details and your schema and rules to try it on a real table.

```
SELECT Staff.FullName, Skills.Name, Staff.Team, StaffSkills.Rating, a.Name as AdditionalSkills
FROM StaffSkills
INNER JOIN Staff 
    ON Staff.Id = StaffSkills.StaffId
INNER JOIN Skills
    ON Skills.Id  =StaffSkills.SkillId
LEFT OUTER JOIN Skills a
    ON a.Id  = StaffSkills.SkillId
WHERE Staff.Team LIKE '%financial services%' AND Skills.Name LIKE '%project management%' OR
    (a.Name LIKE '%SDLC%' OR a.Name LIKE '%prince2%' OR
     a.Name LIKE '%agile%' OR a.Name LIKE '%waterfall%' OR
     a.Name LIKE '%oracle%' OR a.Name LIKE '%stakeholder%' OR
     a.Name LIKE '%leadership%' OR a.Name LIKE '%negotiation%' OR
     a.Name LIKE '%planning%')
```